# Loseless FFMPEG compression that supports windows media player

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, media-player, mp4, avi

I am trying to create a movie file (avi, mp4, etc as long as it support windows media player) from a sequence of png files using ffmpeg.I am using C++ "System("ffmpeg command")" to create the movie files once I create the png files (this shouldn't effect movie creation).  I was able to create a .avi file using the following command,

```
ffmpeg.exe -r 30 -i frame_%7d.png test1.avi
```

Once you create the file it runs in windows media player but does not run in VLC. I have realized, it does lossy compression and the movie is not that high quality (quality decreases with frame rate). I want to have lossless compression (or no compression at all) but needs to be able to play in windows media player. So I tried the following commands,

```
ffmpeg.exe -framerate 30 -i frame_%7d.png -codec copy test2.avi
```

This file ran in VLC but didn't run in windows media player. Then I tried put in "-pix_fmt yuv420p" but still couldn't get it to run in windows media player.

```
ffmpeg.exe -framerate 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i frame_%7d.png -codec copy test2.avi
```

I have also tried using "ffv1" codec and it ran in VLC but not in windows media player

```
ffmpeg.exe -i frame_%7d.png -c:v ffv1 -qscale:v 0 test4.avi
```

So, how do I create a lossless movie file from a sequence of png files using ffmpeg that will run in windows media player?